# Wrong executable path for python in linux

Tags: linux, bash, path

In linux bash, I need to run an application (HTSeq) which uses python. When I run the command I get this error:

> -bash: /app/HTSeq-0.5.3p7/bin/htseq-count: /usr/bin/python26: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

The thing is that I do not have "python26" in my executable path. So in my /usr/bin/ path I have followings:

> /usr/bin/python2.6 
>   /usr/bin/python

I think sometimes I have manually changed something incorrectly. But how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming "python2.6" to "python26" with `sudo mv /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python26`

Comment: I am not a sudoer user.

Comment: You're going to need to put your user in the sudo group then.  If not possible try running the command without sudo.

Comment: This is a cluster system which is used by many users. Do you think I can mv the file name and others would not face any problems? and I can not be sudoer account.

Comment: If you fix it on your user the problem will most likely only be solved for your user account, and not others.

Comment: But do you know why it complains for the " /usr/bin/python26" although it does not exist. I can remember that I did something related to the python versions some days ago but I do not remember what exactly it was :(

Comment: Somewhere along the line you probably renamed some files.  The HTSeq is looking for Python, but it can't find it because no file in _/usr/bin/_ has the proper name it's looking for.

Comment: I can not run mv, it complains for the permission.

Comment: You're going to need some kind of special permission to run _mv_ then.  It's most likely the only way to fix this problem besides maybe reinstalling Python (which would need special privileges anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you don't have sudo rights, you could try this:

First create a symlink,

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 ~/Desktop/python26
```

and then adding the symlink dir to your PATH variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<your account>/Desktop
```